# Regular Expression OR in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, regex, pattern-matching

I am attempting to do the following:

```
<input type="text" id="title" class="u-full-width" pattern="^(hi | hello)$" title "Some messege here">
```

Now what I am trying to make work is for  the regular expression to be either 'hi' or 'hello', but for some reason this or statement does not work. Do I need to escape the | character, I've tried but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: try with `^(hi|hello)$"`

Comment: Regex is not free-form. It matters where you put your whitesplace

Comment: Also you are missing an '=' after `title`, it should be: `title="Some messege here"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by removing spaces, such as:

`pattern="^(hi|hello)$"`